# Netbeans continually prompts to reload / overwrite files on samba share

Tags: samba, netbeans, overwrite

This is something that has been bugging me for ages. When running Netbeans on windows (I've seen this problem in netbeans from before version 7 and in version 8.0) and saving files on a samba share netbeans will frequently think that the file has been updated in the background and will ask if you want to reload and or overwrite the file.

After some time this otherwise helpful prompt can become highly irritating. I've looked before for a solution and found https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191445 which at the time of my previous look (late 2013).

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since I last checked the bug report above a solution has now been mentioned.

The problem is caused by a mismatch in the file modification times on linux vs windows.

It can be resolved by adding these options to the global section of your samba config file ( /etc/samba/smb.conf).

```
[global]
    time server = yes
    dos filetimes = yes
    fake directory create times = yes
    dos filetime resolution = yes
    delete readonly = yes
```

There is more detail on what these options do here: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch11.html